# Joomla 2.5 website lost all the changes I did

Tags: joomla

Suddenly all the changes I've done on a joomla(2.5) site has been lost. reseted to the original state. How can this be anyone?

Comment: Your question is not specific enough and without a real question.

Comment: mention the steps or the changes you did. Your actions are needed to know how this happened. At least you can elaborate your question with few more relevant lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How this can be, is a mistery to all of us (without the log files). How this can be undone, however, is a question worth answering.

One way is to set back your database back-up. That is, obviously, if you have made one.

Another way is to set back any export you would've made that holds the data you are now missing. That is, obviously... you get the point.

If there is no way you have secured your data, it is probably gone. You could contact your server administrator to see if he has any backup data, but other then that your data is gone.